# Change css onclick/unclick

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to change the margin of a DIV with the click/unclick of another DIV.

Have this right now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".model_drop_pane").hide();
    $(".show-hide").click(function() {
        if ($("#body_machine_novideo").css('margin-top', '50px')) {
            $("#body_machine_novideo").css('margin-top', '300px');
            $(".model_drop_pane").slideToggle();
      } else {
            $("#body_machine_novideo").css('margin-top', '50px');
            $(".model_drop_pane").slideToggle();
    }
    });
});
```

The idea is: upon click of the .show-hide DIV, the `#body_machine_novideo` DIV changes it's `margin-top` from 50 to 300px, and also the `.model_drop_pane` DIV is toggled. This part works.

The problem: upon clicking the .show-hide DIV a second time ("unclicking"), the `.model_drop_pane` DIV toggles as it should, however the margin value of the `#body_machine_novideo` DIV isn't reset back to 50px, and remains at 300px.

[A working demo of the problem can be found here](http://www.wes-cor.ca/equipment_chemical.php). Click the Equipment: Chemical Mixing Stand link just below the logo.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the value of `$("#body_machine_novideo").css('margin-top')`, but what you should really do is toggle classes by using the `.toggleClass()` method.

You should create a `class` to add extra margin. Leave presentation issues to CSS, and behaviour or interactivity to JavaScript. Better yet, if the value of `margin-bottom` needs to change in the future, you just have to change your stylesheet, and the JavaScript will still work as expected.

```
// JavaScript
$(".show-hide").click(function(event) {
    $("#body_machine_novideo").toggleClass('more');
    $(".model_drop_pane").slideToggle();
    event.preventDefault(); // Added: prevent the clicking event to execute normally
});
```

And your CSS:

```
/* CSS */
#body_machine_novideo { margin-top:50px; }
#body_machine_novideo.more { margin-top:300px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Examine your state to change your view, don't examine your view to figure out your state.

That is, don't put css in your JS. Don't examine an inline style to see if you've set that style, and then plunk in hardcoded css values in repsonse.  Whether the element has a particular class is your *state*. And CSS simply renders certain classes in certain ways.

**CSS**

```
#body_machine_novideo {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#body_machine_novideo.open {
  margin-top: 300px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".model_drop_pane").hide();
    $(".show-hide").click(function() {
        $("#body_machine_novideo").toggleClass('open');
        $(".model_drop_pane").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

See how much cleaner that is?

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition

```
if ($("#body_machine_novideo").css('margin-top', '50px'))
// This part is always true.
// You are not comparing the values in the first place
```

**To**

```
if ( parseInt($("#body_machine_novideo").css('margin-top'),10) === 50)
```

**OR**

```
if ( +$("#body_machine_novideo").css('margin-top') === 50)
```

Also you seem to be having an error in the console due to which the remaining part of the code might not execute..

**Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'**